# Execute validate_unique when form doesn't include all fields

Tags: django, django-forms

I recently had a situation where the validate_unique method from my model wasn't running.  This is because one of the fields involved in the unique test wasn't included in the form.  I tried many things in the form and the view before landing on this solution: I first injected the field into the object of the UpdateView, then ran the test in the Form in _post_clean.

```
models.py 

class Link(ModelBase):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True,null=False)
    url = models.URLField(max_length=400,blank=False,null=False)
    profile = models.ForeignKey('Profile',null=False,blank=False,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('url','profile')

    class Admin:
        pass

forms.py 

class LinkForm(ModelForm):

    def _post_clean(self):
        ''' Be sure that the instance validate_unique test 
            is run including the profile field '''
        super(LinkForm,self)._post_clean()
        try:
            self.instance.validate_unique(exclude=None)
        except ValidationError as e:
            self._update_errors(e)

    class Meta:
        model = Link
        fields = ['title','url']

views.py 

class LinkUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Link
    form_class = LinkForm

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        ''' Add profile to self.object before kwargs are populated '''

        if hasattr(self, 'object') and self.object and self.profile:
                self.object.profile = profile

        kwargs = super(LinkUpdateView, self).get_form_kwargs()

        return kwargs
```

Is there a better way to do this that doesn't involve overriding an internal function?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem a few time, and I solved it this way:

- I included the field in my form
- I overrided `get_form` in my class based view to hide the field to the user, and give it the value I want.

That way, as the field is included, it triggers validation, but the user can not fill it.

It looked like this:

```
    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        form = super(MyClass, self).get_form(form_class)
        form.fields['some_field'].initial = some_value
        form.fields['some_field'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
        return form
```

Comment: I thought about doing this, but didn't want to write the validation code for the hidden field. Now that I know how to pass additional kwargs to the form I may revive this idea.  Thanks.